# Apriori doesn't work properly with a 0 and 1 dataset

Tags: r, associations, rules, apriori

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
   Cus T C B
1:  C1 0 1 1
2:  C2 0 1 0
3:  C3 0 1 0
4:  C4 0 1 0
5:  C5 0 1 0
6:  C6 0 1 1
```

When I use apriori on this exact dataframe, it produces results like

```
    lhs    rhs                           support confidence lift  count
[1] {}  => {c=0}                       0.8360112  0.8360112    1 616223
[2] {}  => {t=0}                       0.8765905  0.8765905    1 646134
[3] {}  => {a=0}                       0.8953804  0.8953804    1 659984
[4] {}  => {b=0}                       0.9103811  0.9103811    1 671041
[5] {}  => {d=0}                       0.9441812  0.9441812    1 695955
```

I have tried converting this dataframe into transactions bb, and then excluding the results that feature 0 by using

```
excluded <- grep("=0", itemLabels(bb), value = TRUE)
rules = apriori(bb, appearance = list(none = excluded))
```

which only leaves the output with 0 rules.

How do I get some useful results which only feature value=1 in the output of apriori?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to make the columns T, B and C logical with

```
data$T <- as.logical(data$T)
data$B <- as.logical(data$B)
data$C <- as.logical(data$C)
```

and then convert to `transactions`.